# Roslyn compiler server reports different hash version than build task

Tags: c#, .net-core, roslyn, visual-studio-2019

I've built an ASP.NET Core 3.1 app in Visual Studio 2019.

The app was compiling previously and I was able to debug it on the same computer. However without making any changes to the app, I suddenly started getting the error message "Roslyn compiler server reports different hash version than build task"

[image: Roslyn compiler server reports different hash version than build task]

Downloading the repo and debugging on a different computer worked okay, however it's not a resolution for the existing computer.

Comment: Have you tried to delete a `.vs` folder at the root of application?

Comment: Deleting the .vs folder did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What is happening is that compiler was "partally updated" by the visual studio installer. This is a setup issue in Visual Studio.  If you could run https://aka.ms/vscollect.exe and upload the zip file in the temp directory to a new issue on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) the setup team should be able to get to the bottom of this.

In order to resolve your issue you will want to run "repair" the VS intaller.
[image]

Comment: Repairing and then restarting the computer fixed the problem for me.